# Is there any sliding menu with visible column before click?

Tags: layout, android, slidingmenu

I've searched but no result.
I would like have menu where you see still column and when you click on it, it will slide right or left showing the rest of layout. What is more it should slide over my activity.
Any help? 
I'm looking for something like that:

[image]

I found sliding menu from jfeinstein only but when you swipe, your screen is moving also.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[This](https://github.com/StevenRudenko/ActionsContentView) is probably what you need.

Example:

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <shared.ui.actionscontentview.ActionsContentView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:actions_layout="@layout/actions"
        app:actions_spacing="50dp"
        app:content_layout="@layout/content"
        app:shadow_drawable="@drawable/shadow"
        app:shadow_width="8dip"
        app:spacing="64dip"
        app:spacing_type="right_offset" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

- `app:actions_layout="@layout/actions"` - this is the layout for your left side menu. You can put there everything you want
- `app:actions_spacing` - offset from left side in dp - that means how much the left menu will be visible
- `app:content_layout="@layout/content"` - this is the layout for main content. You can also put there everything. For example there you can have a FrameLayout and you can attach a fragment from code based on what menu item a user clicked
- `app:spacing_type="right_offset"` and `app:spacing="64dip"` - that means that when left menu is opened, then how much the main content will be visible

**MainActivity.java:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mSlidingMenu = (ActionsContentView) findViewById(R.id.content);

     //this will open menu
     mSlidingMenu.showActions();

     //this will close menu
     mSlidingMenu.showContent();

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "easier"? I think this lib is very easy to use. Did you have some problems when you were trying it?

Comment: example is ultra complex imho

Comment: I have updated my answer. I still dont think that it is so difficult. If you run original example, there are many options you can change "on the fly" right in the example app. So I suggest to try that example app. It will help you to understand it.